# shifting arrays to 1st element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$important_dates = array(
        array('start_date' => '2013-01-01',
            'end_date' => '2013-12-01'
        ),

        array(
            'start_date' => '2014-01-01',
            'end_date' => '2014-05-03'
        )
);
```

I want to output:

```
$important_dates = array(

        array(
            'start_date' => '2014-01-01',
            'end_date' => '2014-05-03'
        )
);
```

I tried: `$important_dates = array_shift($important_dates);` but failed.
Is it possible to show me your code? It will help a lot. thanks

Comment: Do you want to modify the original array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
array_shift($important_dates);
var_dump($important_dates);
```

`array_shift` removes the first element of the array and returns that element - not the array.

Answer (score 0):

As per the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

It states

> array_shift() shifts the first value of the array off and returns it

So, you are now assigning the first element of `$important_dates` to a new, one-dimensional array.

In other words, `array_shift` **modifies** the array you pass to it, 'deleting' the first element (compare with `pop_front` in c++). The `return` value is that first element. So, you should modify your code to

```
array_shift($important_dates);
```

or, optionally

```
$first_date = array_shift($important_dates);
```